# Codeigniter 3 CI_adminlte routes

Tags: adminlte

Boa noite, há algum tempo que ando a usar o adminlte em CI3 [Tirado daqui](https://github.com/domProjects/CI-AdminLTE/tree/master)

Acontece que ontem passei do localhost para liveserver e á excepção do controller que eu meta como 'default' nas routes(qualquer um que eu coloque como default funciona), todo o resto dá o error '404 not found', este problema até já está reportado lá no git, mas sem resposta. Fiz todas as alterações normais no CI, base_url, DB... já procurei tudo e experimentei acho que todas as sugestões na internet mas sem sucesso, incluindo as capital letters nos controllers e models. Já tentei varios .htacess já tentei sem .htacess mas sempre sem sucesso.

"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at xxx.xxx.xxx.pt Port 80"

Antes demais agradeço atenção.